# getting error on logout from facebook

Tags: android, facebook

i have create an app in whick i m logging in facebook, and getting data from facebook.,but my logout method is not working,what is the problem,i am unable to understand,after launching the app in device whatever id i fill in starting it always getting data from that onle,it is not getting logout and i am unable to login through another id.please suggest me something.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;
Button login,getData,logout;    
ImageView ig;
String app_id;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
     app_id= getString(R.string.app_id);
     fb= new Facebook(app_id);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        getData=(Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
        // ig= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginToFacebook();
                }
            });

getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getProfileInformation();
    }
});
     logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        logoutFromFacebook();

}
}
});
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
//updateButtonImage();

    }





    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {

         mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
         String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
         long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

         if (access_token != null) {
             fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Already Login",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         if (expires != 0) {
             fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Already Login",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
access_token=null;
expires=0;

         }



        if (!fb.isSessionValid()) {
            fb.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    fb.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    fb.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            // Making Login button invisible
                            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making logout Button visible
                            getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });

    }


     @Deprecated
     public void logoutFromFacebook() {

            mAsyncRunner.logout(MainActivity.this, new RequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                    Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // make Login button visible
                                login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                // making all remaining buttons invisible
                                getData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }

                        });

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });
        }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4017
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:86)
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:286)
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:310)
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at com.facebook.Session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(Session.java:614)
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:665)
04-16 17:42:34.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32465):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$1.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:89)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

I hope this will be help to you...

```
  if( mFacebook.isSessionValid() ) {
  try {
    String str=mFacebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
    SessionStore.clear(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)       
                 {                      
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
```

Comment: you will place code in logoutFromFacebook() function

Comment: you have sessionstore class?

Comment: i dont have sessionstore class in sdk,having only session class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50787/discussion-between-android-and-himani)

Comment: try this code....    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}

Session.setActiveSession(null);

Answer (score 0):

Get the Key hashes from your project by putting this code in MainActivity after OnCreate

```
 try {

       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

       for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
       {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }

      } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
       Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
      }
```

Go to logcat and copy the Key hashes from there Then go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and click on your app you created then go to settings paste your key in Key Hashes box and click save changes. Make sure that you app is public and available to all users if not public then go to settings put your email in Contact Email box and click save changes then check the small circle next to app name.
and for Log out simply call logoutFromFacebook(); in onClicklistener. clear your app data in settings and then perform logout.

Comment: @ Kamran Afsar i already done that..,but problem is on logout click i get error

Comment: uninstall your app from device, then after reinstalling it perform login then at this time if you click logout button then you will be easily logged out. if you are already loged in and you run again this app from pc then during logout you app will crash.. also try the below function for logout i posted

Comment: @   Kamran Afsar i tried to do what you told me but now its showing me error key doesnot matches,configure your hashkey from developer.facebook, now

Comment: yes now get the key hashes from logcat by putting the above code after OnCreate and then follow the steps i written above

Comment: means after these lines @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: it is still giving me error  invalid android_key parameter

Comment: copy youe key correctly and paste it in developers.facebook.com and save changes then run your app

Comment: okk done with that..,but in logout still m getting error,same as i post in my logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void logoutFromFacebook() {
  MainActivity.mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {

   @Override
   public void onComplete(final String response, Object state) {
       Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread         
            public void run() {
                Boolean b = true;
                try {

                       editor.remove("access_token");
                      editor.commit();
                     sleep(500);
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                         //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged out from Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // making all remaining buttons invisible
                            getData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });



                    while (b == true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                }
            };
        };
        timer.start();

   }

   @Override
   public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
     Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
     Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
   }
  });
 }
```