# can login through one account only,it is not taking another id for login in facebook

Tags: android, facebook

in my application,i can loging through my facebook id.,it i enter another id,it didnot fetch data,as it do for my id.i can't understand what is the problem.when i enter another id,it showing loading,and after that onle blank facebook page is visible.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;
Button login,getData,logout;    
ImageView ig;
String app_id;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
     app_id= getString(R.string.app_id);
     fb= new Facebook(app_id);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        getData=(Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
        // ig= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginToFacebook();
                }
            });

getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getProfileInformation();
    }
});
     logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        logoutFromFacebook();
    }

}
});
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
//updateButtonImage();
try {

    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
    {
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
     md.update(signature.toByteArray());
     Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
   }    
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            fb.setAccessToken(access_token);

            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
            getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + fb.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "already login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //logoutFromFacebook();
        }

        if (!fb.isSessionValid()) {
            fb.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                         editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    fb.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    fb.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            // Making Login button invisible
                            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making logout Button visible
                            getData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: can you show what error/Logcat out put  you are getting  ?

Comment: @  Rahul Gupta i don't get any error,first of all it donot get logout,and if i tried to enter another id after reinstalling the app,it take the id and password,but after that only blank facebook page with facebook header get visible only,while if i enter my id after login it shows my profile pic with my name

Comment: @  anuruddhika  yes it work.. thank you :)

Comment: @ anuruddhika  can you tell  me what is the problem in my logout too.. please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108055/getting-error-on-logout-from-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it like this.

Go to Facebook developers page

Apps --> "YourApp" --> Status and Review --> Enable ("Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?")

Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create app on Facebook. You might have testing and enabled **sandbox mode** as shown in image.you need to disable it.

Note: don't look at other settings.it is app for web,similarly you will have sandbox option for mobile app.
[image]

Comment: @ Mehul Joisar in my advance setting there is no field name sandbox mode..i think version difference is there

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not updated for latest Facebook SDK 3.8, now Facebook provide Default class for Login, Share, Import Photo from Facebook and much more. Please follow this link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/